# Are these eigenvectors same?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was solving for eigenvector and came across this equation.

$(-\sqrt 3 - \sqrt {11} )x = 4y $ where $(x,y)$ is eigenvector.

So for the eigenvector I wrote $(4,-\sqrt 3 - \sqrt {11} )$.

My question is, is this same as $(-4, \sqrt 3 +\sqrt {11} )$  and  $(1,\frac{-\sqrt 3 - \sqrt {11}}{4} )$ ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes; scalar multiples of eigenvectors are also eigenvectors. Either one is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the vectors you have mentioned are scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: So are they all correct?

Comment: Yes, they are all correct.